# Correlated subquery with common table expressions in SQLite

Tags: optimization, execution-plan, subquery, sqlite, cte

Yesterday I achieved a 500x performance boost after rewriting an `EXISTS` with `IN`. I did some investigation to find out why and finally came to the following example. Basically, we draw 5 lucky numbers out of 0 - 999, and count how many lucky numbers are drawn.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS natural_numbers AS
WITH RECURSIVE natural_numbers(x) AS (
    SELECT 0
    UNION
    SELECT x + 1
    FROM natural_numbers
    LIMIT 1000
)
SELECT x
FROM natural_numbers;


.eqp   ON
.timer ON

WITH lucky_numbers(lucky_number) AS (
    SELECT x
    FROM natural_numbers
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 5
)
SELECT SUM(EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM lucky_numbers
        WHERE x = lucky_number
))
FROM natural_numbers;


WITH lucky_numbers(lucky_number) AS (
    SELECT x
    FROM natural_numbers
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    LIMIT 5
)
SELECT SUM(x IN lucky_numbers)
FROM natural_numbers;
```

The output is

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE natural_numbers
`--CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
   |--CO-ROUTINE 1
   |  |--SCAN TABLE natural_numbers
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
   `--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
4
Run Time: real 0.095 user 0.094819 sys 0.000000
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE natural_numbers
`--LIST SUBQUERY 2
   |--SCAN TABLE natural_numbers
   `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
5
Run Time: real 0.001 user 0.000289 sys 0.000007
```

It seems that `EXISTS` re-executes the common table expression `lucky_numbers` for each `x` (and is consequently much slower), whereas `IN` only executes it once for the whole table (the result is always 5, no more, no less). This is kind of surprising because common table expressions [are supposed to be a view](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#ordinary_common_table_expressions) instead of a temporary table, so I would expect the behavior of `EXISTS`.

---

To complicate things further, if you replace `LIMIT 5` with `LIMIT X` where `X >= 8` in the `EXISTS` clause, its execution plan would become

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE natural_numbers
`--CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
   |--CO-ROUTINE 1
   |  |--SCAN TABLE natural_numbers
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
   `--SEARCH SUBQUERY 1 USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (lucky_number=?)
```

and the result will always be `X` instead of a random variable for `X <= 7`. I suspect this is because the common table expression `lucky_numbers` is no longer re-run for each row, but instead cached in the `AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX`. In other words, the query planner is changing the result of our query here!

---

So, when are common table expressions run for each row / the whole table? Looks like with `IN` it's guaranteed to run only once for the whole table (which is somehow inconsistent with the document's words that [an ordinary common table expression is essentially a pre-packaged SELECT statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#ordinary_common_table_expressions)), but with `EXISTS` things are more complicated and the decision is left to the query planner.

Comment: Cross-posted on the [SQLite forum](https://www.sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/fd23e52c89), since I think it's probably a bug now.